# How to get an object in a function with ng-change when using ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to get an object when the user select a value in the select. I'm using the ng-change to call a function

```
<select ng-model="study.dayIntermediate"
        ng-change="addDay(day)"
        ng-options="day as day.libelle for day in listOfDays | orderBy : 'duration'">
</select>
```

An example of my object :

```
{
    libelle: "question",
    duration: 15
}
```

My function :

```
$scope.addDay = function(day) {
    console.log(day);
}
```

But I get the value undefined.

Does anybody have an idea of what I'm doing wrong please ?

Comment: should be `addDay(study.dayIntermediate)`

Comment: With two way binding, you should already have the selected value in study.dayIntermediate in your function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !